# Showing an operator kernel is nowhere dense...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, baire-category

We are doing a problem that requires us to, for fixed NONZERO element  $h \in L^2[0,1]$ (as in, the function $h$ is not zero on a set of positive measure in $[0,1]$) and fixed  $f \in L^2[0,1]$ with the property that $\int fh =0$, and fixed $\epsilon >0$, find a function $g \in L^2[0,1]$ such that $||f-g||_2<\epsilon$ but $\int hg \neq 0$.

This has proven to be difficult, though intuitively it makes sense. We tried several hatting ideas, and using the fact that $h^2$ must have a nonzero integral, to no resolution. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry again. I'm not sure this will work. Deleting comments.

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't guarantee $\int h^2 \neq 0$

Comment: Are $f$ and $h$ given so that $\int fh=0$ with $\int h^2\ne0$? ($h$ non-zero is equivalent to $\int h^2\ne0$.)

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say you can't guarantee that $\int h^2 \neq 0$ on $A$.

Comment: Wouldn't $g=f+\text{sgn}(h)\epsilon/2$ work?